# flutter UI problem: text feild not scrolling behind stepper

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

### Here when I am scrolling then my text fields which is in grey[200], scroll overe stepper little bit, as you can see in image. so How to fix it?

Here when I am scrolling then my text fields which is in grey[200], scroll overe stepper little bit, as you can see in image. so How to fix it?

This is my stepper code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import '../../../constants/constants.dart';

class BecomeHH extends StatefulWidget {
  const BecomeHH({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BecomeHHState createState() => _BecomeHHState();
}

class _BecomeHHState extends State<BecomeHH> {

  int _activeStepIndex = 0;

  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController cityController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController countryController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController phoneController = TextEditingController();

  List<Step> stepList() => [
        Step(
          isActive: _activeStepIndex >= 0,
          state:
              _activeStepIndex >= 0 ? StepState.complete : StepState.disabled,
          title: const Text('Step One'),
          content: ClipRRect(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Name",
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 3.7,
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: nameController,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      hintText: 'Enter Your Name',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      ),
                      filled: false,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "City",
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 3.7,
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: cityController,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      hintText: 'Enter Your City',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      ),
                      filled: false,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Country",
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 3.7,
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: countryController,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      hintText: 'Enter Your Country',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      ),
                      filled: false,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Email",
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 3.7,
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: emailController,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      hintText: 'Enter Your Email',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      ),
                      filled: false,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Phone",
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 3.7,
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: phoneController,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      hintText: 'Enter Your Phone Number',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      ),
                      filled: false,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Step(
            isActive: _activeStepIndex >= 0,
            state:
                _activeStepIndex >= 1 ? StepState.complete : StepState.disabled,
            title: const Text('Step Two'),
            content: Container(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Video",
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            )),
        Step(
            isActive: _activeStepIndex >= 0,
            state:
                _activeStepIndex >= 2 ? StepState.complete : StepState.disabled,
            title: const Text('Step Three'),
            content: Container(
                child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Focus Area",
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            )))
      ];



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white38,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Theme(
          data: ThemeData(
            colorScheme: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(primary: selectBlueColor),
          ),
          child: Stepper(
            type: StepperType.horizontal,
            currentStep: _activeStepIndex,
            steps: stepList(),
            onStepContinue: () {
              if (_activeStepIndex < (stepList().length - 1)) {

                setState(() {
                  _activeStepIndex += 1;
                });
              } else {
                print('Submited');
              }
            },
            onStepCancel: () {
              if (_activeStepIndex == 0) {
                return;
              }

              setState(() {
                _activeStepIndex -= 1;
              });
            },
            onStepTapped: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                _activeStepIndex = index;
              });
            },
            controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, ControlsDetails details) {
              final isLastStep = _activeStepIndex == stepList().length - 1;
              return Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                          backgroundColor:
                          MaterialStateProperty.all(const Color(0xFF158998)),
                          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                            RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.teal, width: 0.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onPressed: details.onStepContinue,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                          child: (isLastStep)
                              ? const Text('Submit')
                              : const Text('Next'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    if (_activeStepIndex > 0)

                      Expanded(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all(const Color(0xFF158998)),
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.teal, width: 0.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: details.onStepCancel,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                            child: const Text('Back'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this line in your Stepper widget.

```
physics: ScrollPhysics(),
```

Comment: Its not working, My page is scrolling but my grey part of text field is coming on stepper like in Image